# Why this list just go up to september?

Tags: php, loops, date

I have this code

```
<?php
$startYear = 2011;

 while ($startYear <= date('Y')) {
    echo "$startYear <br>";

        for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
            $theDate = $startYear . $m;

            if ($theDate <= date('Yn')) {
                $month = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, $startYear));
                echo $month. '<br>';
            }
        }
    $startYear++;
 };
?>
```

because I would like to write a list of the type

2013

- January
- February
- March
- April
- May
- June
- July
- August
- September
- October
- November
- December

until the current year and the present month

but every list of months of every year just goes until september, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change your if statement from this:

```
if ($theDate <= date('Yn')) {
```

to this:

```
if ($theDate <= date('Ym')) {
                     //^ See here the placeholder for month with leading zero
```

For more information about `date()` see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

Because 201410 > 21049. This is what happens when you use `date()` for date math for which it is not suited.

`DateTime()` and its related functions are better suited for this:

```
$startYear = 2011;

$start    = (new DateTime())->setDate($startYear,1,1);
$end      = (new DateTime())->setDate($startYear,1,1)->modify('+1 year');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) { 
    echo $dt->format('F') . "\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/277352)

If you're using PHP 5.5+ it is a little cleaner

```
$startYear = 2011;

$start    = (new DateTimeImmutable())->setDate($startYear,1,1);
$end      = $start->modify('+1 year');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) { 
    echo $dt->format('F') . "\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/277357)

Answer (score 0):

i edited my code to add a leading zero to the variable who will represent the month number, edited the current date from date('Yn') to date('Ym') and works.

```
<?php
$startYear = 2011;


while ($startYear <= date('Y')) {
    echo "$startYear <br>";

        for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {

            $f = sprintf('%02d', $m);
            $theDate = $startYear . $f;

            if ($theDate <= date('Ym')) {
                $month = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$f, 1, $startYear));
                echo $month. '<br>';
            }
        }
    $startYear++;
};
?>
```

Thanks for the answer guys.

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't think they understand how this site works.

Comment: @JohnConde Seems to be the case